# How to link View to Viewmodel without using BindingContext in xaml.cs page in MAUI

Tags: mvvm, maui

I am using `Commnunity.Toolkit.Mvvm` to use MVVM in my project. I have seen many article, YouTube videos almost everyone at the end link View to Viewmodel using BindingContext. I want to connect it without BindingContext.

How can I avoid this code

```
public partial class ItemEntryPage : ContentPage
{
    public ItemEntryPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ItemEntryPageModel();
    }
}
```

Where do I need to make that connection in `MauiProgram.cs` or in `App.xaml.cs` file or do I need to use different Mvvm nuget package ?

There are few approaches where to not need to worry about `BindingContext` just follow the naming convention of View and Viewmodel, it works, in few cases I have seen in `Xamarin.Forms` we need to keep View and Viewmodel name in `dependency injection` in `App.xaml.cs` file and it works.

I am following this thread [mvvm in .net maui](https://www.androidmads.info/2023/10/mastering-mvvm-deep-dive-into-net-maui.html).

Comment: You have to specify a BindingContext in order to use data binding.

Comment: @Jason - I agree it requires a BindingContext but there could be different ways of doing it in one place for all the pages.

Comment: @R15 You cannot do that, every Page has its own BindingContext. Someone, somewhere, needs to create an instance of the ViewModel. It doesn't happen automatically. Even it you let the built-in dependency injection facility of Shell handle the instantiation, you'll need to pass it down to the Page and set the BindingContext. Implicit binding contexts only work for ContentViews that are added to a Page, because the binding context is "inherited" from the parent.

Comment: You could do that if every page in your app uses the same VM, which would be really unusual.  Or you could create a custom base page class that sets the BindingContext based on some naming convention.  It would help if you explained what problem you’re trying to solve by doing this

Comment: It would still be setting the BindingContext of each page explicitly, just in a different way, e.g. using reflection.

Comment: @R15 You can write Page extension (well not exactly extension), that will find your viewmodel class name, construct an object from that class, and set it as biding context, together with initializing the components of the page. And call it in your constructors. I advise against this choice.

Answer (score 2):

If you have numerous pages, but, they all have the same view model, the recommendation is to use dependency injection and configure that view model as a singleton in your `MauiProgram.cs`:

```cs
// MauiProgram.cs ...
builder.Services.AddSingleton<GlobalViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<SecondPage>();
// ...
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs
public class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(GlobalViewModel VM)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = VM;
    }
}
```

```cs
// SecondPage.xaml.cs
public class SecondPage : ContentPage
{
    public SecondPage(GlobalViewModel VM)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = VM;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to give each page its own transient ViewModel, but, also, within each ViewModel, have access to the global singleton ViewModel, you can do it like this:

```cs
// MauiProgram.cs ...
builder.Services.AddSingleton<GlobalViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<SecondPage>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<SecondViewModel>();
// ...
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs
public class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(MainViewModel VM)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = VM;
    }
}
```

```cs
// MainViewModel.cs
public class MainViewModel
{
    public GlobalViewModel Global { get; }
    public MainViewModel(GlobalViewModel Global)
    {
        this.Global = Global;
    }
}
```

```cs
// SecondPage.xaml.cs
public class SecondPage : ContentPage
{
    public SecondPage(SecondViewModel VM)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = VM;
    }
}
```

```cs
// SecondViewModel.cs
public class SecondViewModel
{
    public GlobalViewModel Global { get; }
    public SecondViewModel(GlobalViewModel Global)
    {
        this.Global = Global;
    }
}
```

If your question is not able global or singleton, but, about avoiding setting `BindingContext` in the c# code behind, you can actually set `BindingContext` in XAML instead, e.g.

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage BindingContext="{local:MainViewModel}"/>
</ContentPage>
```

```xml
<!-- SecondPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage BindingContext="{local:SecondViewModel}"/>
</ContentPage>
```

If you want to declare a singleton global `GlobalViewModel` but just in XAML, one way you could place it in a `ResourceDictionary` in your `App.xaml`:

```xml
<!-- App.xaml ... -->
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:GlobalViewModel x:Key="globalViewModel"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage BindingContext="{x:StaticResource globalViewModel}">
</ContentPage>
```

```xml
<!-- SecondPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage BindingContext="{x:StaticResource globalViewModel}">
</ContentPage>
```

Or, even, just declare it in the `BindingContext` in `App.xaml`:

```xml
<!-- App.xaml ... -->
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
    <Application.BindingContext>
        <local:GlobalViewModel/>
    </Application.BindingContext>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

First we follow the official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/

Instead of random links, that may be not-available (or turn out to contain banana shake recipe) after a month or so.

Second, we do not do this:

```
BindingContext = new ItemEntryPageModel();
```

But we use the Dependency Injection, we have in MAUI by:

1. Register the ViewModel in your MauiProgram.cs.
2. We modify our Page constructor to set the injected ViewModel as BindingContext.

In your case:

```
public ItemEntryPage(ItemEntryViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = vm;
}
```

That is the right way to do it. Nothing else is required.

Anyway, if you want to save some lines of codes using reflection and feel better, this is what I do:

Extension:

```
public static void AddTransientNamespace(this MauiAppBuilder builder, string nameSpace)
        {
            foreach (Type t in Utils.GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), nameSpace))
            {
                builder.Services.AddTransient(t);
            }
        }
```

How to use:

```
builder.AddTransientNamespace("MyProject.ViewModelsNamespace");
```